# Sending email via emote sendmail without smtp-auth and via proxy

Tags: phpmailer, php-7, sendmail.exe

Our PAAS platform needs to send email on behalf of our customers, where the "From" has to be our customer's domain. So our customers have their servers running Sendmail, from which we're supposed to send email to achieve the designated 'From' address.

Usually our customers set up the usual SMTP services with TLS enabled and a username and password configured. Which means, we need to compose body, attach files, assign headers etc, from our PHP code on our server, but the final 'sending' happens via the remote Sendmail SMTP.

Our challenge with some customers: the Sendmail on the remote server has *not* enabled SMTP auth. They merely whitelist our IP.

We run off a shared hosting service, so to give them a more fixed IP that they could whitelist, we use a proxy server. They have whitelisted this proxy server IP on that destination Sendmail server. Could you please advise how we could use php-mailer with a proxy? So settings like the following..

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->PROXY??? = '<our proxy IP here>';
```

There doesn't seem to be any `proxy` option in phpmailer. Any pointers on how, if SMTPAuth is set to false, do we enable the remote Sendmail server to recognize and allow only us? What's the usual pattern in these cases? Thanks.

Comment: Remote sendmail without SMTP makes no sense. What protocol are you going to use to send email if not SMTP?

Comment: @Synchro I meant SMTP without the usual `smtp-auth`, so no username and password.

Comment: In that case set the `Host` property to your proxy's address, and configure the SMTP relay running on the proxy to forward traffic from there. The client script doesn't have to know about it.